# What would be a good way to pass UserID (Forms Authentication) to the DB Context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass the UserID (Forms Authentication) to the DB Context class which will call an overload of SaveChanges(). This over loaded function would first calla stored proc to set DBSession context for auditing and then will call the base SaveChanges().

The question here is what is a good approach to send the User id to this DBContext class (I have made UserId as a property of this class) from the Controller without explicitly calling it every time. 
I want something which would be just fired every time and pass on the UserId to DBContext class without writing code for it each time.

```
    public partial class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DataContext")
    {
    }

    public DataContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {

    }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        SetDbSession();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

private void SetDbSession()
    {
        //Open a connection to the database so the session is set up
        this.Database.Connection.Open();
        //Set the db session
        //ExecuteSqlCommand ot to be used as it will close the connection
        using (var cmd = this.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            var parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
            parm.ParameterName = "@userId";
            parm.Value = UserID ;
            cmd.CommandText = "SetDbSession";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    };
}
```

This is the DB Context class, all I want is to pass UserId into it, in a way which doesn't make it cumbersome to be used across.

Comment: Could you please clarify your intent?  maybe post some code examples?

Comment: I have added the DB context class

Answer (score 0):

You could inject it into the constructor:

```
public partial class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    private string _userID; 
    public DataContext(string userID)
        : base("name=DataContext")
    {
         _userID = userID;
    }

    public DataContext(string userID, DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        _userID = userID;
    }           

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        SetDbSession();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void SetDbSession()
    {
        //Open a connection to the database so the session is set up
        this.Database.Connection.Open();
        //Set the db session
        //ExecuteSqlCommand ot to be used as it will close the connection
        using (var cmd = this.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            var parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
            parm.ParameterName = "@userId";
            parm.Value = _userID;
            cmd.CommandText = "SetDbSession";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    };
}
```

When creating your DB Context in a controller:

```
var context = new DataContext(User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: The DBContext is created at service level, Services are already injected in the controller. So a way is needed in which a developer doesn't have to keep passing on that identity and it should reach the db context in the best possible way.

Comment: If your DBContext is injected in the controller then you should also be able to inject the UserID into the controller. 

Are you using a dependency injection framework? If so, which one?

Comment: DbContext is not injected in the controller, DbContext is injected only at Service layer (Which is a middle layer), Only services are injected in controllers. We are using Autofac.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC and Autofac, one way would be to inject HttpContextBase to your service layers through an abstraction.

```
public class MyHttpAbstraction :IMyHttpAbstraction {
     public MyHttpAbstraction (HttpContextbase httpContextBase) { _httpContextBase = httpContextBase; }
     public string GetUserId() {
          return _httpContextBase.User.Identity.GetUserId();
     }
}
```

and in your type registrations

```
builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).As<HttpContextBase>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

This way the concrete implementations of your service can depend on `MyHttpAbstraction` rather than know HttpContextBase directly.  You can string along this dependency all the way down to your IDataContext.  If you want to go crazy, feel free to abstract DbContext and IDataContext out and create an intermediary class that takes DbContext as a dependency and implements IDataContext:

```
public class MyDataContext : IDataContext {
      public MyDataContext(DbContext context, IMyHttpAbstraction myHttpAbstraction) { _context = context; _myHttpAbstraction = myHttpAbstraction; }
//...feel free to implement
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is pretty much what I am looking for but  injecting IMyHttpAbstraction doesn't work as autofac cannot resolve it . builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).As<HttpContextBase>().InstancePerHttpRequest(); doesn't resolve IMyHttpAbstraction

Comment: I'm curious if the Autofac binding is the issue? Did you try any other ones aside from InstancePerHttpRequest()?

Comment: yes I did try other ones but I don't know why it should even work, unless I am missing something here,  IMyHttpAbstraction is not even being used in the builder builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).As<HttpContextBase>().InstancePerHttpRe‌​quest(); So how is it suppose to work